# http://127.0.0.1:8080/apex/f?p=4950 loading issue on 64-bit

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, oracle-apex, oracle11gr2

I am using a 64-bit laptop and I seem to have the common issue of not being able to load oracle "get started" service -part of the 11g express edition.

Its on port 8080 and I tried a few things such as re installing again.
SP2-0640 is Not Connected.

OracleXEClrAgent is not on start.

I have looked through oracle forums seem to find the answer no where. Can anyone who experienced such problems or know how to fix this help.

PLATFORM: WINDOWS 7
Oracle Database Express Edition 11g Release 2 for Windows x32

Comment: Which operating system are you using? Which version of Oracle? (Did you consider mysql or mariadb?). And you question is not appropriate here, because not related to source code.

Comment: windows 7, express edition currently on oracle site

Answer (score 1):

Oracle 11G Express edition is not supported on windows 7 64 bit.

Oracle Database Express Edition 11g Release 2 for Windows x32
- Does not work in Windows x64

It says on the Oracle site.

http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/products/express-edition/downloads/index.html

Comment: I've witnessed a few friends on windows x64 running perfectly